# How to remove view rendered templete in expression engine

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have a site that implemented in Expression Engine,and in admin pannel while iam editing any template, at top right I have noticed one button "**view rendered template**" and while clicking on it it will take me to old template...

I want to hide or disable that button,how can I approach it can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this extension and jquery to hide the button:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js

Comment: Thats a good extension but is it the better way to hide the button..??through the console he can display it by changing the css right..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it,

If you goto system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/design.php   comment this line

```
$this->cp->set_right_nav(array(
     'view_rendered_template' => $vars['view_path']
));
```

Comment: Not wise, as that means you will not be able to update ExpressionEngine without the risk of that file being updated and overwriting your hack. Hence the use of an add-on to resolve the issue.

Comment: As @Chego suggested, if you're worried that the client could hack it via the console to display the button, then delete it via Jquery `$("#templateViewLink").remove();` instead of hiding via CSS. Alternatively you'd need to write your own extension to tap into the relevant Control Panel hook: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/ but this would be overkill and a lot of unnecessary effort.